# PySpark value with comma doesn't contain comma?? (Trying to cast to ArrayType(StringType()))

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am running PySpark v1.6.0, and I have a column of string values (according to .printSchema), but when I attempt to filter the rows according to cases where the column value starts with a "[" character or contains a "," character, in both cases, it's saying that the rows that I'm expecting to evaluate to True are still False...

When I run the code:

```
col_name = "attempt_params_attempt_response_id"
resultDF.select(col_name, resultDF[col_name].like(",")).show(50)
```

I get:

[image: Picture where column value should be true but is false]

I don't understand how this is possible because the string value clearly contains a comma, so that row should return `true`, not `false`.

Similarly, when I try casting the rows to `ArrayType(StringType())` (which is my ultimate goal), it also behaves as if my rows don't contain a comma...

When I run the code:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, IntegerType, StringType

col_name = "attempt_params_attempt_response_id"
resultDF.withColumn(col_name, 
                    split(resultDF[col_name], ",\s*")
                    .cast(ArrayType(StringType()))).select(col_name).show(40)
```

I get the results:

[image: Multidimensional array as if there was no comma to split on]

I wonder if perhaps there's some sort of bizarre encoding issue that is causing the character `,` to not match the character that in the data appears to be a `,` character... but I really am not sure. Any ideas on why this is happening and how I can actually get the cast to work without creating the text of a multi-dimensional array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case your pattern is wrong. `like` is equivalent to SQL like using simple regular expression, so `,` matches only literal `,`.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("[0,2,3]", ), (",", )], ("text", ))
df.withColumn("contains_comma", col("text").like(",")).show()
```

```
+-------+--------------+
|   text|contains_comma|
+-------+--------------+
|[0,2,3]|         false|
|      ,|          true|
+-------+--------------+
```

To get a match you should add leading and trailing wildcards:

```
df.withColumn("contains_comma", col("text").like("%,%")).show()


# +-------+--------------+
# |   text|contains_comma|
# +-------+--------------+
# |[0,2,3]|          true|
# |      ,|          true|
# +-------+--------------+
```

In the second case there is no problem at all. Since you split on `,` the first item will contain a leading `[`

```
df.withColumn("contains_comma", split("text", ",\s*")[0]).show()
```

```
+-------+--------------+
|   text|contains_comma|
+-------+--------------+
|[0,2,3]|            [0|
|      ,|              |
+-------+--------------+
```

and the last trailing `]`. You should strip these if you don't want them in the output, for example using [`regexp_replace`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=regexp_replace#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace):

```
split(regexp_replace("text", "^\[|\]$",  ""), ",")
```

Comment: I also tried .startsWith("["), and those cases were all false too. Do I also need to add a wildcard for that to work?

Comment: For `startsWith` no. It uses fixed value as a pattern. However without [reproducible exmample](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48427185/6910411) it is not possible to say what is the problem, and it doesn't seem to directly related to the ones you have described here.

Comment: I was able to get your example to work after modifying your regex pattern to `"^\[|\]$"`